# GCM push not received on device with Postman or Node modules

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to set up my own server to handle the `GCM` push notifications in my Android Phone App, and I've run into a problem that puzzles me.

I'm trying to send push notifications by using `Postman` like this:

```
Request Type: POST

URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

Header
  Authorization  : key=your key //Google API KEY
  Content-Type : application/json

JSON (raw) :
{       
  "registration_ids":["yours"],
  "data": {
    "Hello" : "World"
  } 
}
```

and I'm getting a response like this:

```
{
  "multicast_id": 7360389950846966696,
  "success": 1,
  "failure": 0,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "message_id": "0:1466937961332908%e66a7eb3f9fd7ecd"
    }
  ]
}
```

which seems like everything went like it should, but no notification is received on the device. I've also been trying multiple `GCM` modules for Node.js, with the `same result`: everything seems to work out like it should, but no notification is received.

However if I'm using this neat little website for testing GCM, the notifications are being received:
[gcm-notification-test-tool-android](http://techzog.com/development/gcm-notification-test-tool-android/)

At the website, no other information than what is being used in the Postman request is being provided, so this makes little sense to me.

Any suggestions on how to solve this and why it happens.

Comment: How do you handle the request on your device ? Let us have a look at your onReceive() function of the GCM Broadtcast Receiver, please.

Comment: @Gil I'm using an Android Phone, so all I'm doing is registering for push and no onReceive function is being used.

Comment: did you find the solution for this? i am also getting same problem.

Comment: @Gil can't remember how i got it to work, but make sure you've implemented the necessary notification handlers and given permission in androidmanifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Sound strange, so how do you parse the JSON returned by the Server ? Anyway, are you using "message" attribute like in the link you send above ? It looks as if you sending "Hello" as the key and on the link you are sending "message".